# Convert from .mat to .obj

Tags: matlab, 3d

I have several mat files-X.mat, Y.mat, Z.mat, X2.mat, Y2.mat, Z2.mat and tri.mat.
I'm looking for a way to convert each of those file to .obj extension in order I'll be able to print it as 3D model. 
Can you assist pls?

Thanks!

Comment: Code to write wavefront obj is available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27982-wavefront-obj-toolbox)

Comment: Thanks you! As I understood write_wobj function is expected to obj file but I would like to convert .mat to .obj file. Can you pls assist?

Answer (score 1):

Matfiles can contain arbitrary data, while wavefront obj files contain very specific data. That's why a generic mat to obj conversion is not possible.

[write_wobj](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27982-wavefront-obj-toolbox/content//write_wobj.m) can write a struct to a obj file, but you have to load your matfile and copy it into a struct with the required format.

Comment: Thanks! what is the first and second parameter meaning?

Comment: I saw the first param is OBJ and the second is fullfilename but what is the meaning of those? I have .mat file

Comment: The file comes with a documentation.